# jQuery - wait for user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm experiencing quire a nasty problem. Here it goes:

My script uploads file(s) and responds back with a JSON encoded object, which contains file ID numbers that need additional information.

Now, the problem. I'd like to display a dialog (a form) and wait for user to fill it, send it via AJAX back to server, and then repeat the same process for the second ID number, and so on.

I tried to do this using $.each, but unsuccessfully. I read $.each can be terminated by returning false in callback function, but I did not find anything mentioning how to wait for an event (let's say submit button in my form to be clicked) and then continuing the loop.

Nice day

### Solution:

```
coll_id = 0;      // collection pointer

collection = [
    {
        id : 4,
        fileName : 'somefile.mp3'
    },
    {
        id : 6,
        fileName : 'anotherFile.mp3'
    }
];

function openDialog(){

    $('#browser-add-files-id3').bind('dialogclose', function(){
        if(coll_id >= collection.length-1){
            try{
                closeDialog(collection[coll_id].id);
            }
            catch(err){

            }

            coll_id++;
        }
        else {
            closeDialog(collection[coll_id].id);
            coll_id++;
            openDialog();
        }
    });

    $('#id3-file').text(collection[coll_id].fileName);
    $('#browser-add-files-id3').dialog('open');
}

function closeDialog(mid){
    // $.post to /url/param/mid
    // cleanup the input fileds in dialog
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not mix asynchronous behavior with .each() which is synchronous. What you could do is loop over all items with .each(), and check if you find one that hasn't been processed. If so you mark it as processed, fire the asynchronous request, and then return false to stop each().

In the asynchronous success callback, you just trigger the .each() loop again, it will skip all processed items, and if one is found that hasn't been processed, mark it as such and start the async request, etc.

For marking items as processed, I'd recommend using `$(item).data('processed', true)` or anything alike using jQuery's data function.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I'm just wondering ... how does alert() do it? Because I'd need the same functionality, only with jQuery dialogs ;)

Comment: Alert is a modal (blocking) dialog from the browser. If you want to do it easily but in a quick and dirty way you can use `prompt('Provide this detail')`, then the return value will be whatever the user entered in the box that pops up. It'll work, allowing you to ask the user for all infos and then send that via an ajax request once you collected all that's needed, but let's be honest, from a user experience point of view, `confirm()` has stopped being a sexy solution in the 90's :)

Comment: Exactly :)
Well, after reading your answer once again, and a lot of brainstorming, I've got this thing working somehow ... very nasty solution, but will have to do. 
I wonder if jQuery developers have adding something for this purpose in their minds, I'd be useful.
Anyway, question updated with solution, and I'll accept your asnwer ... just because it's new years eve ;P